# error while assigning to a variable in c++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

i am trying to create a binary tree in c++. This is the tree

```
    3
   / \
  2   5
```

i just want to manually create this tree for testing some algorithms on this tree. Below is my code for the same, but i get this error. why is it so?

```
binary_tree.cpp:19:21: error: expected type-specifier before ‘node’
   root->right = new node(5);
```

.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(int data){
      this->data = data;
    }
};

int main(){

  Node *root = new Node(3); //creates a node called root and initialises its data field to 3
  root->left = new node(2); //to the var left inside root to a new instance of Node ??
  root->right = new node(5);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:Thankyou everyone for your valuable response. if i want to represent this tree:

```
      3
     / \ 
    2   5
   / \ 
  1   4
```

i have made these changes:

```
  Node *root = new Node(3);
  root->left = new Node(2);
  root->right = new Node(5);

  root->left->left = new Node(1);
  root->left->right= new Node(4);
```

is it correct? i mean do i have to set left and right of leaves node as null explicitly so that i can print the tree?

Comment: `Node` instead of `node`

Comment: @Ari0nhh thanks so much. how could i miss that ! such a shame :(

Comment: Node(int data){
      this->data = data; left =nullptr;right =nullptr;
    }

Comment: why don't initialize all data in the constructor?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc what do you mean and what benefits does it have?please provide answer in little detail

Comment: I mean why do you only initialize data and leave `left`, `right` as is? Look at user1438832's comment

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc ok thanks got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is **case senstive**. You must use identifiers exactly as they are declared. "node" is not the same as "Node".

In addtion, leaf termination in a binary tree should have some designation. In your case, assigning `NULL` to leaf terminated sub-nodes seems reasonable.

You can do this automatically by assigning `NULL` in `Node::Node(int)`. Change your code from...

```
Node(int data) {
    this->data = data;
};
```

... to...

```
Node(int data) {
    this->data = data;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
};
```

After that, you know that all newly created nodes are terminated by default and iterating (for something like printing) won't be a problem as long as you check for children being `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be capital N,

```
root->left = new Node(2); 
root->right = new Node(5);
```